# PHP Echo to a certain part of HTML

Tags: php, html, sql

I recently finished my login system but I have a question about PHP. How can I echo text or html to a certain part of html?

For example. Lets say the code below is all inside one PHP file. How could I echo the 2 echos in the php code to the html where the comment is?

So if I were to display this page and if their login failed it would echo "The username and password you entered did not match our records. Please double-check and try again." to that comment in the html.

I hope that makes sense, Thanks!

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
        include_once("db.php");
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($sqlcon, $_POST['username']);
        $username = strtoupper($username);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($sqlcon, $_POST['password']);

        for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
            $password = hash(sha512, $password . $username);
        }

        $userQuery = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" . $username . "' LIMIT 1";
        $user = mysqli_query($sqlcon, $userQuery);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($user) > 0) {
            $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($user);
            $id = $user['id'];
            $databasepass = $user['password'];

            if ($password === $databasepass) {
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
                header("Location: admin.php");
            } else {
                echo "The username and password you entered did not match our records. Please double-check and try again.";
            }
        } else {
            echo "The username and password you entered did not match our records. Please double-check and try again.";
        }
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ADMIN</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <!--ECHO THOSE TWO ECHOS ABOVE HERE-->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd personally recommend looking into MVCs. It'll help keep code clean and separate your html from php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign the text to a variable and use PHP down inside your HTML to echo that.

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
        include_once("db.php");
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($sqlcon, $_POST['username']);
        $username = strtoupper($username);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($sqlcon, $_POST['password']);

        for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
            $password = hash(sha512, $password . $username);
        }

        $userQuery = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" . $username . "' LIMIT 1";
        $user = mysqli_query($sqlcon, $userQuery);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($user) > 0) {
            $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($user);
            $id = $user['id'];
            $databasepass = $user['password'];

            if ($password === $databasepass) {
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
                header("Location: admin.php");
            } else {
                $result = "The username and password you entered did not match our records. Please double-check and try again.";
            }
        } else {
            $result = "The username and password you entered did not match our records. Please double-check and try again.";
        }
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ADMIN</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <?php echo $result; ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Change `echo` in your code to variable, eg. `$message = "......";`

then inside your div

```
<?php

echo $message;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

if $message is not set it would throw an error, so why not either use:

```
<?=isset($message)?$message:"";?>
```

of you can initialise

```
$message = "";
```

in your code then display $message / $result as prescribed by Jacob See & rishal